# Access to folder is denied

Tags: meteor, deployment

In my app i created folder “.app/” where users keep their uploaded files. I made such a name (with dot) to prevent meteor watch this folder. Because otherwise when user creates new folder server reboots.

But when I’ve deployed my app It crashes when user tries to create folder.
“Access to .app folder - denied”.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: check your folder permissions

Answer (score 0):

Usually the docker file system is read-only for the meteor process, which is why it fails. If you really want local file acces (not a great idea anyway, think about using Filestack or an AWS S3 bucket instead), well you will need to add a volume which is writeable, and will survive a docker image being blown away (which you occasionally will need to do).